# Python groupby warning : IndexError boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0;

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing what I think is a simple groupby statement on a pandas dataframe using the following:

```
count = x.groupby(
        pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='M'))['support_type'].value_counts()
```

However, this throws the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "cat_test.py", line 62, in
>   
>       pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='M'))['support_type'].value_counts()   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line
>   3171, in value_counts
>       labels = list(map(rep, self.grouper.recons_labels)) + [llab(lab, inc)]   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line
>   3141, in 
>       llab = lambda lab, inc: lab[inc]
>
> IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 0 but
>   corresponding boolean dimension is 1

Comment: I think that you forgot some parenthesis...

Comment: should mix the `'` and `"` to make difference with key and the string parameter

Comment: @PRMoureu - no the single and dbl ticks make a difference

Comment: @JejeBelfort - Correct - the code sample has been updated - The problem persists I simply typo'd the original example.

Comment: my comment was for the first version, anyway, syntax looks correct now, you need to check the input datas

Comment: I think you can't just use value_counts on the groupby. Try to add apply(lambda x: x) before value_counts(), should work

Comment: The root cause of this issue was caused by the data slice I was taking for the df. If the data slice was less than 1 month, the error would occur. If it was >= 1 month the code worked correctly.